# AWS lambda function call another lambda function with parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to make two lambda function, one call the other with parameter, the called function print the parameter out.I got trouble to make it works:
The first function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import json

lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    invoke_response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="called-function",
                                           InvocationType='Event',
                                           Payload=json.dumps('hello Jenny'))
                                           )
    print(invoke_response)
```

Please advise what code should I put in the called-function in order to receive the parameter 'hello Jenny'?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Payload` supplied in the params will be available as the `event` of the Lambda being invoked.

```
def add(event, context):
    # event is 'hello Jenny'
    return event
```

Comment: really appreciate

Comment: Now the function runs successful, but why the first function return null?   Response:
null

Comment: You are not returning anything from first function. Also note that `InvocationType` of your second function is `Event` which is asynchronous i.e. response only contains status code 202. Read more in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_ResponseSyntax)